# C# Selenium - OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException - Element could not be scrolled into view

Tags: c#, selenium

I am currently trying to click an element on a webpage using selenium with C#.  I need to click a Div element based on a child element that has the text 'Test App'.

Here is the HTML snippet for the object;

```
<div class="application_items">
    <a href="www.google.com" target="_self">
        <div class="homePageItems">
           <div class="small" style="display: block;">
               <div class="AppLabel">Test App</div>
           </div>
           <div class="big" style="display: none;">
               <div class="AppLabel">Test App</div>
                   <div class="underTitle"></div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </a></div>
```

And here is my C# code to try access the first appearance of the app name 'Test App';

```
Element(By.XPath("//div[@class='small']/*[text()[contains(., 'Test App')]]"));
```

When this runs, I get an error;

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'Element <div class="AppLabel"> could not be scrolled into view'
```

I thought the error may be because the program was accessing the second occurence of 'App Test', so I have tried setting the div with the class 'big' visible (display: block;) with the following code, but it doesn't seem to help;

```
IWebElement elem = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='small']/div[text()[contains(., 'Test App')]]"));

String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.display='block';";

((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript(js, elem);
```

I apologise if something similar to this has been asked before, I spent a while browsing similar subjects but didn't find what I needed.  If anyone could please point me in the right direction, that would be  much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all the elements, filter them down to only the visible ones, and then click the first (or whatever) one.

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elems = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[.='Test App']")).Where(e => e.Displayed).ToList();
elems.ElementAt(0).Click();
```

It's also possible that you need to add a wait to make sure that part of the page has loaded.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much.  I used this and also added a wait, and now everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can siply use by using classname, Correct the code as I dont know the C sharp very well

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("AppLabel")).Click();
```

Also you can use xpath

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(“//div[@class='small']/div[text()='Test App'])).Click();
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a perfect solution for the problem I described.  However, this HTML block is replicated for many apps - I need to code something that can select an app based from user input (I did not mention this, I apologise).

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have provided to click on the first appearance of the app with text as **Test App** you can use either of the following line of code :

- `CssSelector` :

  ```
  Element(By.CssSelector("div.homePageItems > div.small > div.AppLabel"));
  ```
- `XPath` :

  ```
  Element(By.XPath("//div[@class='homePageItems']/div[@class='small']/div[@class='AppLabel' and contains(., 'Test App')]"));
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but unfortunately I still get an error. I ended up using the code suggested by JeffC.  Perhaps this may help you in the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elems = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[.='Test App']")).Where(e => e.Displayed).ToList();
elems.ElementAt(0).Click();
```

I am using this its perfectly working for me